# WHMCS API - Trying to post data from a html form

Tags: php, html, whmcs

I understand PHP pretty well however I have never had to deal with curl before today so I'm having a bit of an issue understanding how I am supposed to submit data to WHMCS API

I have made a simple HTML form on my website but I'm trying to make the following code obtains the variables such as subject and message I have tried many different ways and I keep getting error 500 and I can't find a guide on the WHMCS forum there seems to be a few which might work however these topics have been removed as there old I'm guessing

The following code is what WHMCS gives you to work with all I need is some help to understand how I format the variables coming from my form

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '####'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
            'action' => 'OpenTicket',
            'username' => '#',
            'password' => '#',
            'accesskey' => '#',
            'deptid' => '1',
            'subject' => 'This is a sample ticket',            
            'message' => 'Demo Text',
            'email' => 'demo@demo.com',
            'name' => 'Demo User',
            'priority' => 'Medium',
            'markdown' => true,
            'responsetype' => 'json',
        ) ) ); 
$response = curl_exec($ch); 
curl_close($ch);
?>`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the posted variables from the $_POST array, e.g.  $_POST['example'] will contain the value of example input element of the submitted form.

For the form (as an example, we will get subject and email as inputs):

```
<form action="" method="post">
Subject: <input type="text" name="subject" value="" /><br />
Email: <input type="email" name="email" value="" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="btnAct" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

For the API:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['btnAct'])) {
    //ToDo: sanitize inputs, use filter_var() for example
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, '####'); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array(
                'action' => 'OpenTicket',
                'username' => '#',
                'password' => '#',
                'accesskey' => '#',
                'deptid' => '1',
                'subject' => $subject,            
                'message' => 'Demo Text',
                'email' => $email,
                'name' => 'Demo User',
                'priority' => 'Medium',
                'markdown' => true,
                'responsetype' => 'json',
            ) ) ); 
    $response = curl_exec($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);

}
```